# Ubuntu 12.10 not starting after USB install on a netbook

Tags: 12.10, startup, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a Asus Eee PC "flare series" from a USB key made with LiLi (Linux Live USB creator). The installation process seems to work fine until it asks to reboot the netbook. Then, it only displays a black screen with a blinking white "_" with no possible interaction. I've tried to run it in live-disk mode from the USB key, with exactly the same result. The only thing that seems to interact with it is pressing the power button: It seems then to shut down properly, displaying several lines like "exiting acpid" to "will now halt".

I've tested the USB key on another computer, and it works fine.
The netbook is less than 2 days old.

Comment: Is the blank screen with the blinking `_` cursor *before* or *after* it reboots at the end of the initial installation?

Comment: It occurs after it reboots. All the process before the reboot seems to be normal.

Comment: In that case, take a look at [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)